# How to run an FTP server locally that a docker container can connect to

Tags: node.js, docker, networking, ftp

I'm currently running vsftpd locally on port 21 and have a node program that pulls data from it and that also works great.

I have containerised the deployment of the program on my local machine and it deploys fine but complains it can't connect to the FTP server on port 21 which I realised was because that port wasn't open.

Now if I open that port with something like -p 21:21 then this is blocking the FTP server which is bound to 21. I don't understand how I can run a test FTP server and this container at the same time?

Is it possible?

Comment: You cannot have multiple programs run on same port,  just choose another one.

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

If the "containerised program" is only the node app, then if you connect to the ftp server via localhost:21 it will fail because inside that container there is no ftp server running on port 21. If you want to use the ftp server that runs on your host os, you need to run the container with `--net="host"`, then the node app should connect to the ftp server with 127.0.0.1:21.

Another approach would be creating another container for the ftp server and using docker dns system to communicate the containers.